# Angular CLI - ng serve with seperate backend server

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server, lite-server

I am in the process of converting a custom webpack built angular application to the Angular CLI and everything seems to be working well except I can't figure out how to get `ng serve` to work. I have about 11 applications within this Angular work-space and the one main app talks to the others, like the login application for example. running `ng serve main` works fine at first and the application starts but then is immediately redirected to `localhost:4200/login` to get authenticated but the problem is that my IIS application is running on `localhost:9000` and so when it tries to get the login application there is an error `Cannot GET /login`.

My question is: how can I setup `ng serve` to work with all of these applications?

All of the source code had been built to the dist folder so `/dist/login` is ready to be served.
I have tried various arguments to the serve command as well as trying to serve from the same port that my IIS server is using but in that case I get `EACCES: permission denied` errors. I'm not the most experienced with the IIS side of things but if the problem can be resolved in that realm I can get help from a senior dev.

Can this be solved with [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server)?

Really any input will be helpful, I am a little lost on where to even look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After trying lite-server and reading through more documentation, I stumbled upon [proxying to a backend server](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server). This configuration option allows you to setup a proxy for any requests going to a backend server on another port and forward them to the correct address.

Simply setup a `proxy.conf.json` file that tells the webpack-dev-server where to redirect the traffic:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Then in your `angular.json` set the serve options to look for your proxy file:

```
...
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
...
```

The requests for external files will now correctly be routed to your backend server running on port 3000!